# Adjectives and adverbs: "continuously marked footpath" or "continuous marked footpath"

Tags: meaning, adjectives, adverbs

I have a question about when we should use adjective or adverb in the following sentences. Does it depend on what we want to say or we just can not use one of the following expressions?

> **Authentically** stained glass is colored while the glass is in a liquid state.
>
> **Authentic** stained glass is colored while the glass is in a liquid state.

In the sentence above can we use "authentically" to describe the adjective "stained"? Or we only can use "authentic" to describe glass.

> The Appalachian Trail, extending approximately 2020 miles from Maine
> to Georgia, is the longest **continuously** marked footpath in the
> world.
>
> The Appalachian Trail, extending approximately 2020 miles from Maine
> to Georgia, is the longest **continuous** marked footpath in the
> world.

And the same question about the second example and words "continuously" (continuously marked) and "continuous" (continuous footpath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Authentically stained glass**, sounds awkward to me, but its meaning would be about how the glass was stained:

> **Authentically stained** glass has very strict rules to adhere to.

**Authentic** stained glass refers to the origin of the stained glass:

> **Authentic** Peruvian stained glass comes from high in the Andes.

The second example can be read (commas inserted for clarity):

> 1) longest **continuously** marked footpath
>   2) longest, **continuous**, marked footpath

#1 is a footpath that has continuous markings along it, though the path itself may have breaks
#2 is a path that has no breaks, and also has markings on it, but the markings maybe not be as frequently as on a *continuously marked footpath*